# How to use ModelMapper for deep inheritance objects?

Tags: java, dto, modelmapper

**A.java**

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@Inheritance
@JsonTypeInfo(use=JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, inclue=JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property="type") 
@JsonSubTypes({
    @JsonSubTypes.Type(value=AA.class,name="aa"),
    @JsonSubTypes.Type(value=AB.class,name="ab"),
})
public abstract class A {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    //json ignore for getter
    @ManyToOne
    private A parent;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="parent")
    private List<A> children;
}
```

**AA.java**

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@DiscriminatorValue("aa")
public class AA extends A{
    private User user;
}
```

**AB.java**

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@DiscriminatorValue("ab")
public class AB extends A {
    private String name;
}
```

Now, when I return an instance of class **`AB`** as JSON, it looks like this:

```
{
     "id": 1,
     "type": "ab",
     "children": [...],
     "name": "ali"
}
```

Since I want to use a custom `User` JSON, I want to use [ModelMapper](http://modelmapper.org). All things are Ok except Absence of **`type`**.

My DTOs:

```
@Getter
@Setter
public class ADto {
     private Long id;

     private List<ADto> children;
}

@Getter
@Setter
public class AADto extends ADto {
     private UserDto user;
}

@Getter
@Setter
public class ABDto extends ADto {
     private String name;
}
```

**How can I use [ModelMapper](http://modelmapper.org) and get `type` of class?**

Comment: Are you sure the example is correct? For example, `AB ` is not used anywhere and it has only one filed but it's json has 4 fields. Could you reformat/shortly your questions so that it is clear what you need.

Comment: @OleksandrShpota you are right, `AA` and `AB` extends class `A`.

Answer (score 1):

Possible solutions:

1. Have you tried to add the attribute type in the parent class? This should be enough if you retrieve this field from the DB.
2. A simple tested trick, add `protected String type = this.getClass().getSimpleName().toLowerCase();`. Notice that it must be *protected*. Here's my tested code:

   ```
   @Data
   abstract class A {
     protected String type = this.getClass().getSimpleName().toLowerCase();
   }

    class AB extends A {}

    class AA extends A {}

    @Test
    public void test(){
       A a1 = new AB();
       A a2 = new AA();
       assertThat(a1.getType()).isEqualTo("ab");
       assertThat(a2.getType()).isEqualTo("aa");
    }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You can InheritanceType when you define parent class which will help to show the child type of class

Ex-
A.java

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.JOINED) // change needed 
@JsonTypeInfo(use=JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, inclue=JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property="type") 
@JsonSubTypes({
    @JsonSubTypes.Type(value=AA.class,name="aa"),
    @JsonSubTypes.Type(value=AB.class,name="ab"),
})
public abstract class A {
```

Answer (score 0):

There is now type map for solving this problem. See the [type-map-inheritence](http://modelmapper.org/user-manual/type-map-inheritance/) documentation.

```
// Creates a base TypeMap with explicit mappings
TypeMap<BaseSrc, BaseDest> typeMap = modelMapper.createTypeMap(BaseSrc.class, BaseDest.class)
    .addMapping(BaseSrc::getFirstName, BaseDest::setName);

typeMap.include(SrcA.class, DestA.class)
    .include(SrcB.class, DestB.class)
    .include(SrcC.class, DestC.class);
```